# Changing URLs on Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I have several questions about changing URLs on firebase.

1. Can I change `some-name-123.firebaseapp.com` to `other-name-123.firebase.app.com`?
2. Can I change `custom.example.com` to `example.com` without removing the custom domain and adding it back again (for which I assume there will be downtime)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you cannot change the `myapp.firebaseapp.com` domain of an existing app. You may be able to register the other name that you are looking for and thus gain `othername.firebaseapp.com` too.
2. Reach out for firebase-support@google.com and they may be able to do this for you without downtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to add a custom domain inside `Hosting` section.